# How to add the static data into the Dynamic array in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I want to add the static contents into the Mutable Array. I have parsed the data using XML parsing and stored the dynamic data into the mutable array. Now i want to add the static string into that Mutable Array. So how can i add that?

For Eg:

In my dynamic Array of content is,

```
  {
       first,
       third, 
       fourth,
       fifth.
  }
```

I want to add the static String into the 1st index of array. Because my requirement is, displayed the static content into the 1st position.

Expected output:

```
  {
       first,
       second,   //Add the static data into the First index of Array 
       third, 
       fourth,
       fifth.
  }
```

So how can i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating NSMutableArray from XML parsing you can implement like this,

suppoose In XMLArray you having your xml data now you want to insert static date at any location,

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray=[NSMutable array];
for(int i=0;i<[XMLArray count];i++)
{
  if(i==1)//accrding to you
      [tempArray addObject:yourStaticData];//yourStaticData is object having your data.
  else
    [tempArray addObject:[XMLArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}

//use tempArray according to you.
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean. You can use:

```
[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]
```

Supposing myArray is the instance of NSMutableArray:

```
[myArray insertObject:@"second" atIndex:1];
```

instead of NSString you can insert every object you want.